# annotation @Mock is disallowed for this location in spring junit testcase

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I am writing unit test for spring controller. My controller is based on Rest API and I am using @RequestBody and @ResponseBody annotation to support that.
I am getting the “The annotation @Mock is disallowed for this location” error when using @Mock annotation.please suggest.

My Test class is like Below:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
Public class ControllerTest{

Controller1 controller1;

Public void init(){
    controller1= new Controller1 ();
}


@Test
Public voidd test(){
    ServiceAdaptorClass ServiceAdap= new MockUp<ServiceAdaptorClass>{
            @Mock  // getting error here that “The annotation @Mock is disallowed for this location”
            ReturnType methodname( arg1,arg2) throws Exception{
                 ReturnType returntype;
                 returntype.setProperty(…..);
                 return returntype;
                }
        }.getMockInstance(); 

    mockmvc.perform("url");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"@Mock is disallowed for this location" is kind of generic error and it comes if import is missing for that annotation.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 @Mock annotations:

```
import mockit.Mock
```

and

```
import org.mockito.Mock
```

Perhaps you use both in your test, so just add full import path for one of annotations you are using.